# switch onClick buttons

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I have three buttons

```
Button1 btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button2 btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button3 btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
btn3.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {

switch(v){
 case bt1:
 //SOME CODE
 break;
 case bt2:
 //SOME CODE
 break;
 case bt3:
 //SOME CODE
 break;


}
```

It breaks when it gets to the switch, can anyone help me? first post hope everythings ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
     public void onClick(View v) {

     switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.button1:
     //SOME CODE
     break;
     case R.id.button2:
     //SOME CODE
     break;
     case R.id.button3:
     //SOME CODE
     break;
 }
```

- The view is passed into the onClick
- Therefore switch should look for the view, not the button name.

Answer (score 5):

change it in

```
    Button1 btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button2 btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button3 btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
btn3.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {

switch(v.getId()){
 case R.id.button1:
 //SOME CODE
 break;
 case R.id.button2:
 //SOME CODE
 break;
 case R.id.button3:
 //SOME CODE
 break;


}
```